# Conditional rendering using data from an API in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, I'm building an application that monitors foreign exchange prices. It allows a user to input a price of a selected currency pair that they would like to be alerted once the inputted price is reached. I have tried using conditional rendering to do this but am only getting alerted on the same price that i have just put in the Textinput instead of monitoring the prices. Below is the code:

//Condition

```
 const CheckAlertCondition = () => {
   
   if( {...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk}  >= pricealert )
   {
    return(
      Alert.alert("Target reached", "Price"+ pricealert+"has been hit")
    )
   }
   else if({...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutBid} <= pricealert) {
     return(
       Alert.alert("Target reached", "Price"+ pricealert+"has been hit")
     )
   }
   
   return false
  

 }

<Modal
          visible={modalopen}
          animationType={"fade"}
          >
            <View style={styles.modal}>
              <View>
                <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
               {currency.data.prices[clickedindex].instrument}
              </Text>
              <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
              {currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk}/{currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutBid}
              </Text>
              <Card.Divider/>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                
                    <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          value={pricealert}
          onChangeText = {(pricealert) => setPricealert(pricealert)}
          placeholder="Alert Price"
          placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
          numeric
          keyboardType='decimal-pad'    
        />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                
        


                </View>

              </View>   
          <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() =>
            ActionSheet.show(
              {
                options: BUTTONS,
                cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
                destructiveButtonIndex: DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
                title: "How do you want to receive your notification"
              },
              buttonIndex => {
                setSheet({ clicked: BUTTONS[buttonIndex] });
              }
            )}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            <Text>ActionSheet</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>





                   
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
               onPress={() => {setModalOpen(false); CheckAlertCondition();showToastWithGravityAndOffset();} }>
                <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>OK</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
```

Comment: Why do you put the alert statement inside a return? I don't see why that function would need to return anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for that correction.Upon changing, the output is still the same